# zip file isn't generating in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar, zip

I've multiple modules in my gradle project. I want all the source code jars and dependencies jars to be in lib folder and it should be zipped to upload on repository. I've written the code as per my (a newbie's) understanding but I'm not sure why isn't it working.

```
myProject's build.gradle

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

tasks.register("projectDistribution", Zip) {
  group = 'build'
  dependsOn jar
  archiveName = 'myProject.zip'
  duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
  project.getTasksByName('distZip', true).each{task ->
     dependsOn task
     task.enabled = false
     task.archiveName = task.project.name
     with task
  }

  from (jar){
    into 'myProject/lib'
  }

  from(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.findAll {it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { it }) {
    into 'myProject/lib'
  }

  from(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.findAll {it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }) 
  {
    into 'myProject/lib'
  }

buildscript{
  repositories {
    maven {
      url uri('http://myRepoUrl')
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.spring.grale:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.7.RELEASE'
  }
}
```

This is my module's gradle.build file

```
buildscript{
  repositories {
    maven {
      url uri('http://myRepoUrl')
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre'
  }
}

plugin{
  id 'java'
}

repositories{
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile project(":myModule2")
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre'
}

task distZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: [ jar ]) {
  baseName = 'myProject'
  duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'

  from (jar){
    into 'myProject/lib'
  }

  from(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.findAll {it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { it }) {
    into 'myProject/lib'
  }

}
```

According to me, this code should create a distributions folder in build which should have a zip file with all the jars. But I do not see the distribution folder itself. Can you please guide me understand my mistake.

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I found that on executing distZip task, it generates distribution folder and a zip file as expected. But on executing 'gradle clean build' it doesn't generate any distribution folder. I noticed in logs that loop isn't calling distZip task.I tihnk, there is some issue with project's build file,